Spring Data MongoRepository count of records group by multiple fields with projection
I am trying to build an aggregation pipeline for spring boot mongo repository interface method. The requirement is to group by multiple fields of the document and return count of each group.
In simple SQL query, it is something like below.
select field1, field2, field3, count(*) as count from document where status = ?

I tried the below aggregation pipeline, the count works but the fields are populated as null.
@Aggregation(
        pipeline = {
            "{$group: { _id: { field1: '$field1', field2: '$field2', field3: '$field3', field4: '$field4', field5: '$field5' } } }",
            "{$project:  {status: ?0}}",
            "{$count :  'count'}"
        })
List<MyAggregate> findAllGroups(String status);

What am I doing wrong?

You need to include count(*) in group stage.
Try this:
@Aggregation(
    pipeline = {
        "{$match: {status: ?0}}",
        "{$group: { _id: { field1: '$field1', field2: '$field2', field3: '$field3', field4: '$field4', field5: '$field5' }, count: {$sum:1} } }",
        "{$project:  {_id: -1, field1:'$_id.field1', field2:'$_id.field2',field3:"$_id.field3", field4:"$_id.field4", field5:"$_id.field5", count:1}}"
    })
List<MyAggregate> findAllGroups(String status);

